# How to add wsdl with several ServicePort such CMIS WebServices to WSO API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I have a problem with publishing web services from a wsdl file such us CMIS Web Services.
Have can i manage my services

Comment: i'am not clear that what u want to do. you need to expose your backend services via ESB (wrapper) ? what you mean by "how can i manage" ?

Comment: I have the CMIS webservices(SOAP) that defined in the wsdl file. But in the wsdl file contains several ServicePort such as: - cmis/services/RepositoryService; - /cmis/services/VersioningService; - cmis/services/NavigationService; How can I add webservices on the API Publisher if i can add only one production service url but I need several endpoints

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are mixing two different concepts. You use the same endpoint (production service), but in order to use different serviceport you have to use the parameter SOAP Action in the API published, not to use different endpoint, that if neccesary you can do it with dynamic endpoints feature. If you follow this tutotial from official documentation from WSO2, it is clear:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Create+and+Publish+a+SOAP+API

BR